# Probability that population goes extinct v.s. probability that population eventually goes extinct

Tags: stochastic-processes

Is there a difference between answering the questions:

1. What is the probability that a population goes extinct?
2. What is the probability that a population **eventually** goes extinct?

For example, let $p_i$ be the probability that a parent has $i$ children,

$ \ \  p_0=0.5$, $ \ \ p_1=0.25$, $ \ \ p_2=0.25$

Then, is the answer for question one, simply $0.5$, and is the answer for question two $1$ (found by solving $h(z)=z$, where $h(z)$ is a probability generating function and $z$ is the probability of eventually going extinct)? Or should the answer for both questions be $1$?

Comment: A population either goes extinct or it doesn't. There is no middle way. The "eventually" could perhaps imply that the population first grows and then ultimately goes extinct.  Nonetheless, I don't see a difference in the 2 questions.

Comment: The first question is a little ambiguous, but if I saw that question the first thing I would guess it means is the second question.

Comment: Me too: I agree with  Qiaochu Yuan